# C# Xml Linq, populate list of certain object type

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list

So I'm trying to populate an Xml Document into a list of an object, I managed to retrieve single nodes, but the problem is I want to select several!

Here is the object

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string Date{get;set;}
}
```

And here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfFeed xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <XmlItem Name="Test">
    <Items>
      <SubItem>
        <Title>Some Title</Title>
        <Date>Fri, 30 Oct</Date>
      </SubItem>
      <SubItem>
        <Title>Some Title</Title>
        <Date>Fri, 30 Oct</Date>
      </SubItem>
    </items>
  </XmlItem>
</ArrayOfFeed>
```

And here's my code. As I said before, I manage to select only the first subitem in the XML, I want to select all. Tried to play around with it but no success so far.

```
var itemToFind = "Test"
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(location);
IEnumerable<Item> result = (from c in doc.Descendants("XmlItem")
                               where c.Attribute("Name").Value == itemToFind
                               let r = c.Element("Items")
                               let z = r.Element("SubItem")

                               select new Item()
                               {
                                   Title = (string)z.Element("Title"),
                                   Date = (string)z.Element("Date"),
                               }).ToList();

return result;
```

Help would really be appreciated :)

Comment: So what happens with your current code? And why are you creating objects of type FeedItem instead of Item? Why are you trying to assign to properties title and date instead of Title and Date? Why are you calling `Cast<Item>().ToList()` at the end? Are you actually looking for SubItems rather than XmlItems? (Your Item class only has a single title/date, suggesting it belongs to SubItem rather than XmlItem...)

Comment: Is there more than one `XmlItem` element with attribute `Name="Test"` in your XML?

Comment: Sorry, I had to rewrite my code to make it simpler to understand what I wanted, so had some typos, should be corrected now.
About the cast I had at the end, I just threw it in there because it gave me exceptions.

Im looking for all the subitems values, like Title and Date, and I want to retrieve all of them where/if XmlElements attribute match, 

Sorry, hope it makes more sense :)

Comment: If you have solved your issue, please post the solution as an answer rather than an update to the question, if it has not already been covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with XmlDocuments than XDocuments, but here is what I'd do:

- Load the XML into an XmlDocument (doc)
- Get a collection of nodes using the `SelectNodes` method with the parameter being an `XPath` to the Node(s) you want to be in your collection - I assume you want to find all `XmlItem` nodes with an attribute of Name="Test".
- Foreach `XmlNode` in that collection (an `XmlNodeList` is returned from `SelectNodes`), you will need to use `SelectNodes` to get all `SubItems` nodes
- Loop on this second collection (of `SubItems`) and create your new Item, and use the SelectSingleNode method to get the Title and Date values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Your closing tag for Items needs a capital I.  I used ParseExact to convert date string to a DateTime.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                    "<ArrayOfFeed xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                      "<XmlItem Name=\"Test\">" +
                        "<Items>" +
                          "<SubItem>" +
                            "<Title>Some Title</Title>" +
                            "<Date>Fri, 30 Oct</Date>" +
                          "</SubItem>" +
                          "<SubItem>" +
                            "<Title>Some Title</Title>" +
                            "<Date>Fri, 30 Oct</Date>" +
                          "</SubItem>" +
                        "</Items>" +
                      "</XmlItem>" +
                    "</ArrayOfFeed>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            string itemToFind = "Test";

            List<Item> items = doc.Descendants("XmlItem").Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == itemToFind).Descendants("SubItem").Select(y => new Item
            {
                Title = y.Element("Title").Value,
                Date = DateTime.ParseExact(y.Element("Date").Value, "ddd, dd MMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }


}
​
```

Comment: You missed the `itemToFind` filter.